# Evaluate arguments passed to a macro that generates functions in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to make a macro that defines an accessor function for every config based on the config object created by `py-configparser`:

```
(defmacro make-config-accessor (config section option)
  ; create an upper case function name then intern
  (let* ((fun-name (intern (string-upcase
                             (str:replace-all "_" "-"
                                              (str:concat "get-" option)))))) 
    `(defun ,fun-name (config)
       (py-configparser:get-option config ,section ,option))))
```

It works fine if `option` is passed into as a string, but not when it's a pair like `(car ("db" . "test.db"))`, the form is passed as is and causes error.. How do I evaluate the `option` argument within the macro, without using `eval`.

Full example: Suppose I have a `test.ini` file:

```
[Settings]
db = "test.db"
```

Using `py-configparser` (you can install it with `(ql:quickload "py-configparser")`, you can turn the config file into a Lisp object:

```
(setf *test-config* (py-configparser:make-config))
(py-configparser:read-files *test-config* '("~/test.ini"))
```

This should be the output:

```
#S(PY-CONFIGPARSER:CONFIG
   :DEFAULTS #S(PY-CONFIGPARSER::SECTION :NAME "DEFAULT" :OPTIONS NIL)
   :SECTIONS (#S(PY-CONFIGPARSER::SECTION
                 :NAME "Settings"
                 :OPTIONS (("db" . "\"test.db\""))))
   :OPTION-NAME-TRANSFORM-FN #<FUNCTION STRING-DOWNCASE>
   :SECTION-NAME-TRANSFORM-FN #<FUNCTION IDENTITY>)
("~/test.ini")
```

Then, you can retrieve the `db` option like this:

```
(py-configparser:get-option *test-config* "Settings" "db")
```

The output:

```
"\"test.db\""
```

Now I am writing a macro to create a function for every option such as `db`, like `(get-db *test-config*)` should give me the same output.

I made it work with `make-config-accessor` macro above, but then when I passed a form like `(car ("db" . "test.db"))`, I must use `eval` otherwise the `str:concat` fails.

I made a `gen-accessors` that loops over every options in a config object and generate an accessor for it:

```
(defun gen-accessors (config)
  (let ((sections (py-configparser:sections config)))
    (loop for s in sections
       do (loop for i in (py-configparser:items config s)
             do (let* ((o (car i)))
                  (make-config-accessor config s o))))))
```

Comment: if you want a string, by concatenating two strings, both items need to be strings. If your one input is a list or cons cell, you would need to convert it to a string -> use princ-to-string, format, or anything other which produces a string.

Comment: why are you using functions from STR ? str:replace-all here would be the built-in `SUBSTITUTE #\_ #\- ...`and STR:CONCAT is either CONCATENATE or FORMAT NIL ...

Comment: Macros create syntax,. Could you please show us how you are going to use the syntax and what the expansion is supposed to be? It doesn't seem like `config` is used anywhere in the macro.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Oh I actually mean if I pass a pair with but getting the first element like `(car '("db" . "test.db"))`, the form is passed as is.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I use the package `cl-str` because it's just a package with utility functions making it shorter to type. If I was to not use it, I would have make my own version anyway.

Comment: @Sylwester it is used inside the `defun` that the macro is going to generate. I am using this macro to generate getter functions, i.e. instead of writing `(py-configparser:get-option-config *config-tree* "Settings" "db")`, I can simply write `(get-db *config-tree*)`.

Comment: The problem here is that `make-config-accessor` needs to be a function, not a macro.  See my answer.

Comment: You are blending compile time and runtime. Passing `(car something)` to a macro won't evaluate the argument. That is the whole point of macros to change code to other code. You should perhaps move the whole thing to compile time instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of writing macros is: if you find yourself using `eval` then you have almost certainly made a mistake.  In this case the mistake you've made is that you don't want a macro at all: you want a function.

In particular you probably want this function or something like it:

```
(defun make-config-accessor (section option)
  ;; Make an accessor for OPTION in SECTION with a suitable name
  (let ((fun-name (intern (nsubstitute #\- #\_
                                       (format nil "GET-~A"
                                               (string-upcase option))))))
    (setf (symbol-function fun-name)
          (lambda (config)
            (py-configparser:get-option config section option)))
    fun-name)))
```

Then given a suitable config reader

```
(defun read-config (&rest files)
  (py-configparser:read-files (py-configparser:make-config)
                              files))
```

together with a rather simplified (less single-use bindings) version of your `gen-accessors`:

```
(defun gen-accessors (config)
  (loop for s in (py-configparser:sections config)
        appending (loop for i in (py-configparser:items config s)
                        collect (make-config-accessor s (car i)))))
```

Then, for instance if `/tmp/x.ini` contains

```
[Settings]
db = "test.db"
scrunge = 12
```

Then

```
 > (gen-accessors (read-config "/tmp/x.ini"))
(get-scrunge get-db)

> (get-scrunge (read-config "/tmp/x.ini"))
"12"
```

---

You can make the definition of `make-config-accessor` perhaps even nicer with something like this:

```
(defun curryr (f &rest trailing-args)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (declare (dynamic-extent args))
    (apply f (append args trailing-args))))

(defun make-config-accessor (section option)
  ;; Make an accessor for OPTION in SECTION with a suitable name
  (let ((fun-name (intern (nsubstitute #\- #\_
                                       (format nil "GET-~A"
                                               (string-upcase option))))))
    (setf (symbol-function fun-name)
          (curryr #'py-configparser:get-option section option))
    fun-name))
```

Not everyone will find this nicer, of course.

Comment: This is a great approach. Thanks for showing me a better way.

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the rare cases, where you have to use `eval` in combination with a backquoted macro call with unquoting the arguments.

(I stumbled over this construct once and called it myself `eval-over-macro-call`. - Following the naming tradition `let-over-lambda`. - Actually it should be named `eval-over-backquoted-macro-call-with-unquoting`. It allows you to use macros dynamically. Vsevolod Dyomkin also [stumbled over it](https://lisp-univ-etc.blogspot.com/2020/06/eval-spotted-in-wild.html), independently. I answered him, because I stumbled over it around the same time or before. Macros - as you realized - don't allow arbitrary control over evaluation.)

But first, I generated some helper functions.
(You can use your `:str` package functions, but I had problems to install it. Less dependencies is better. And me, personally, I would prefer `cl-ppcre` for replacements etc.
However, in your case, one can get rid of any dependencies.

`intern` pollutes your namespace. You want only the function namespace have the `get-` function name entries. But not the variable namespace. Therefore, to only return symbols without interning them automatically, use `read-from-string`.

The `dotted-list-p` function requires `:alexandria` package. However, one needs it anyway mostly and since it is one of the most frequently used packages in common lisp shpere (together with `:cl-ppcre`) I think that doesn't count as "additional dependency".

For the `dotted-pair-p` function, I had to do some searches.

The `dotted-list-to-list` converter function, I wrote myself.

You could get rid of all the `dotted-list` functions, if you would use simple string lists for `options`.

In that case in the macro, simply use `listp` instead of `dotted-list-p`.
And use `option` instead of `(dotted-list-to-list option)`.

```
;; one character replacement
(substitute #\+ #\Space "a simple example")
            replacer find obj

(defun string-to-upper-symbol (str)
  (read-from-string (substitute #\- #\_ (format nil "get-~A" str))))

(ql:quickload :alexandria)

(defun dotted-list-p (x)
  (and (not (alexandria:proper-list-p x))
       (consp x)))
;; correct - but gives nil if empty list (or (null x) ...) would include empty list

(defun dotted-or-empty-list-p (x)
  (or (null x) (dotted-list-p x)))
;; this gives t for empty list and dotted lists

(defun dotted-pair-p (x)
  (and (not (listp (cdr x))) (consp x)))

(defun dotted-list-to-list (dotted-list &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null dotted-list) (nreverse acc))
        ((dotted-pair-p dotted-list) (dotted-list-to-list '() (cons (cdr dotted-list) 
                                                                    (cons (car dotted-list) 
                                                                          acc))))
        (t (dotted-list-to-list (cdr dotted-list) (cons (car dotted-list) acc)))))
```

Your macro contains in arguments list `config` which however is never used.

In case you just forgot to unquote the `config` in the macro, the correct solution will be:

```
(defmacro %make-config-accessor (config section option)
  ; create an upper case function name then intern
  (let* ((fun-name (string-to-upper-symbol option)))
    `(defun ,fun-name (,config)
       (py-configparser:get-option ,config ,section ,option)))))

(defun make-config-accessor (config section option)
  (if (dotted-list-p option)
      (loop for x in (dotted-list-to-list option)
            do (eval `(%make-config-accessor ,config ,section ,x)))
      (%make-config-accessor config section option)))

;; call with
;; (make-config-accessor '<your-config> '<your-section> '("option1" "option2" . "option3"))
;; test for existence
;; #'get-option1
;; #'get-option2
;; #'get-option3
```

In the other case, that you don't need config, the correct solution will be:

```
(defmacro %make-config-accessor (section option)
  ; create an upper case function name then intern
  (let* ((fun-name (string-to-upper-symbol option)))
    `(defun ,fun-name (config)
       (py-configparser:get-option config ,section ,option)))))

(defun make-config-accessor (section option)
  (if (dotted-list-p option)
      (loop for x in (dotted-list-to-list option)
            do (eval `(%make-config-accessor ,section ,x)))
      (%make-config-accessor section option)))

;; call with
;; (make-config-accessor '<your-section> '("option1" "option2" . "option3"))
;; test for existence
;; #'get-option1
;; #'get-option2
;; #'get-option3
```

Note, since you need a function, you have to quote in the call the arguments `config` and `section` (they wait for evaluation while in the function-round the `option` gets evaluated.

Thanks to `quote` and `backquote` and `unquote` and `eval` you have full control over evaluation levels in lisp.

Sometimes, one has to use more `quote`s in argument list, if one wants to have
control over several rounds of evaluations.

You could also fuse helper-macro and function into one macro.
However, then, every time you call the macro, you have to use this
`eval-over-backquoted-macro-call` unquoting the desired argument.

```
(defmacro make-config-accessor (section option)
  (if (dotted-list-p option)
      (loop for x in (dotted-list-to-list option)
            do (eval `(make-config-accessor ,section ,x)))
      `(defun ,(string-to-upper-symbol c) (config)
         (py-configparser:get-option config ,section ,option))))

;; call it with
;; (eval `(make-config-accessor <your-section> ,<your-option>))
;; e.g.
;; (eval `(make-config-accessor <your-section> ,'("opt1" "opt2" . "opt3")))
;; test existence with
;; #'get-opt1
;; #'get-opt2
;; #'get-opt3
```

Btw. I don't buy anymore this "`eval` is forbidden" talking.
In cases like this - mostly evaluation control in macros, one has to `eval` as the only alternative to have to write an extra mini interpreter for this problem ... which would be much more tedious (and very likely also more error prone).

You didn't give workable code. So I had to figure all this out with some tody functions/macros, I wrote.

```
(defmacro q (b c)
  `(defun ,(string-to-upper-symbol c) (a) (list a ,b ,c)))

(defun q-fun (b c)
  (if (dotted-list-p c)
      (loop for x in (dotted-list-to-list c)
            do (eval `(q ,b ,x)))
      (q b c)))

;; (q "b" "c")
;; (q "b" '("d" . "e"))
;; (macroexpand-1 '(q "b" '("d" . "e")))

(defmacro p (b c)
  (if (dotted-list-p c)
      (loop for x in (dotted-list-to-list c)
            do (eval `(p ,b ,x)))
      `(defun ,(string-to-upper-symbol c) (a) (list a ,b ,c))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I updated the original post with a full example.

Answer (score 1):

You need two levels of evaluation.

Try:

```
(defmacro make-config-accessor (config section option)
  ; create an upper case function name then intern
  `(let* ((fun-name (intern (string-upcase 
                            (str:replace-all "_" "-" (str:concat "get-" ,option)))))) 
     (eval `(defun ,fun-name (config)
              (py-configparser:get-option config ,,section ,,option)))))
```

Now `option` is evaluated in the `let*` form.
And the returned `defun` form  then needs to be evaluated (which is always in the global scope, or null lexical environment, or toplevel) using `eval`.

Thats all the change that was needed for me to run your code correctly.
Just for reference I'm adding the whole code I ran here (note: there is a change in `gen-accessors`, I think you meant to use `config` and not `*config*`).

```
(ql:quickload "str")
(ql:quickload "py-configparser")

(defmacro make-config-accessor (config section option)
  ; create an upper case function name then intern
  `(let* ((fun-name (intern (string-upcase 
                              (str:replace-all "_" "-" 
                                               (str:concat "get-" ,option)))))) 
     (eval `(defun ,fun-name (config)
              (py-configparser:get-option config ,,section ,,option)))))

(defun gen-accessors (config)
  (let ((sections (py-configparser:sections config)))
    (loop for s in sections
          do (loop for i in (py-configparser:items config s)
                   do (let* ((o (car i)))
                        (make-config-accessor config s o))))))

(setf *test-config* (py-configparser:make-config))
(py-configparser:read-files *test-config* '("~/Desktop/test.ini"))
(gen-accessors *test-config*)

(get-db *test-config*)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. It's nice to see that you can use comma more than once.